# How to send a message from other java controllers to an Akka actor in play?

Tags: java, playframework, akka

I've implemented a basic web socket example with Akka actor, this is the code i used in the Play framework application controller:

```
public static WebSocket<String> socket() {
    return WebSocket.whenReady((in, out) -> {
        // create a new UserActor and give it the default stocks to watch
        final ActorRef messageActor = Akka.system().actorOf(Props.create(MyWebSocketActor.class, out),"SocketActor");
        // List<String> defaultStocks = Play.application().configuration().getStringList("default.stocks");
        // send all WebSocket message to the UserActor
        in.onMessage(message -> {
            // parse the JSON into Stock.Watch
            messageActor.tell(message, ActorRef.noSender());
        });
        // on close, tell the userActor to shutdown
        in.onClose(() -> {
            // kill actor
            Akka.system().stop(messageActor);
        });
    });
}
```

Now in another controller, let's say a Messages controller, I want to pass a message to the actor, in order to push the message in the socket. So in the other controller I setup an ActorSelection:

```
ActorSelection myActorSel = Akka.system().actorSelection("SocketActor");
Object message = "test";
myActorSel.tell(message, ActorRef.noSender());
```

But I've got an error message, in the Akka logger:

```
Message from [] to [] was not delivered [1]. Dead letter encountered.
```

As I've found on internet this means that the actor is not accessible to the other controller or that the actor is not active any more.
Someone point me out to setup a supervisor as a possible solution but, I've found any example in java. Could someone help me or point me out to some resources?

Comment: I am just guessing here, but have you tried to also add the user guardian to the path: `Akka.system().actorSelection("/user/SocketActor");` ?

Comment: no, I'll try later and I let you know. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you create actor on somewhere else and pass its ActorRef to WebSocket and other Controller?